# Multiple columns in aggregated expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been struggling with an elegant solution for this for a while, and thought I'd finally cracked it but am now getting the error

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column referenced in the expression.

Which is frustrating me!

In essence the query is:

```
select 
u.username + ' ' + u.surname,
CASE WHEN ugt.type = 'Contract'
  THEN
    (
      select sum(dbo.GET_INVOICE_WEEKLY_AVERAGE_VALUE(pc.placementid, u.UserId)) 
                from PlacementConsultants pc
                where pc.UserId = u.UserId
                and pc.CommissionPerc >= 80
    )
  END
from usergradetypes ugt
inner join usergrades ug on ug.gradeid = ugt.usergradetypeid
inner join users u on u.userid = ug.userid
```

The function GET_INVOICE_WEEKLY_AVERAGE_VALUE is as follows

```
ALTER function [dbo].[GET_INVOICE_WEEKLY_AVERAGE_VALUE]( @placementid INT, @userid INT )
RETURNS numeric(9,2)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @retVal numeric(9,2)
    DECLARE @rollingweeks int

    SET @rollingweeks = (select ISNULL(rollingweeks,26) FROM UserGradeTypes ugt 
                            inner join UserGrades ug on ugt.UserGradeTypeID = ug.gradeid
                            WHERE ug.userid = @userid)
    SELECT @retVal =
                 sum(dbo.GET_INVOICE_NET_VALUE(id.InvoiceId)) / @rollingweeks from PlacementInvoices pli 
inner join invoicedetails id on id.invoiceid = pli.InvoiceId
where pli.PlacementID = @placementid
and pli.CreatedOn between DATEADD(ww,-@rollingweeks,getdate()) and GETDATE()


RETURN @retVal
```

The query runs fine without the sum but when I'm trying to sum the value of the deals, it's falling over (which I need to do for a summary page)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What happens if you replace `u.UserId` with `pc.UserId` in the function call?

Comment: @Mihai Fair enough, but I don't understand why when I run a function I can't simply do a sum on it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it accepts the command!  Thanks - why does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why this fails:

```
select sum(dbo.GET_INVOICE_WEEKLY_AVERAGE_VALUE(pc.placementid, u.UserId))
```

but this works:

```
select sum(dbo.GET_INVOICE_WEEKLY_AVERAGE_VALUE(pc.placementid, pc.UserId))
```

It is curious and *seems* like a bug to me.

The error message, though, suggests that all the columns inside the `sum()` need to come from *either* the outer referenced tables *or* the inner referenced tables, but not both. I don't understand the reason for this. My best guess is that mixing the two types of references confuses the optimizer.

I haven't seen this error message before, by the way.

EDIT:

It is very easy to reproduce, and does not require a function call:

```
with t as (select 1 as col)
    select t.*,
           (select sum(t2.col + t.col) from t t2) as newcol
    from t;
```

Very interesting. I think this might violate the standard. The equivalent query does run on Oracle.